# View a cusom image on SendGrid dynamic template

Tags: sendgrid

I've been using SendGrid dynamic templates for some time now. I want to start using custom images for the emails sent, however with no success.

I attach the base64 images as `.png` attachments, and in the template editor, use an HTML to render the image, using it `src` as `cid` . The image is sent as an attachment, but is not rendered on the dedicates placeholder.

That's the attachment section:

```
const email = {
             from: ``, // sender address
             to: '',
            unsubscribeLink: `${this.baseUrl}${emailAlertParams.unsubscribeLink}`,
             personalizations:[
                 {
                    'dynamic_template_data': {
                         ...emailPlanParams,
                         ...emailAlertParams
                     }
                 }
              ],
              attachments: [
                {
                    cid: 'planmap',
                    content_id: 'planmap',
                    filename: 'plan_map.png',
                    content: emailPlanParams.firstPlan.map,
                    encoding: 'base64'
                }
            ],
```

And that's the HTML section code from the dynamic template editor:

```
<img src="cid::planmap" alt="Plan Map" border="0" align="center" style="width:100%; max-width: 600px; margin-bottom: 20px; height: auto; background: #dddddd;">
```

That's a screenshot of the image received:
[image]

Thank you guys!

Answer (score 2):

Answer is:

1. use this syntacx for the image

`<img src="cid:planmap"...`

2. Add `disposition:inline` to the attachment:

```
content: emailPlanParams.firstPlan.map,
                    encoding: 'base64',
                    disposition: 'inline',
```